# Fast enumeration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently developing a game and need really fast enumeration of arrays. I need to run the code 30 times per second and now want to ask what's the best way to accomplish the task.
I want to enumerate an array and modify it at the same time.

I know 2 at the moment:

```
NSMutableArray*array;

int i=0;

int x=0;
 for (myclass*spr in [[array copy] autorelease]) {
    if ([spr isInBounds]) {
        //do something
    } else {
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:x];
        x--;
    }

    x++;
}
```

and

```
int x=0;

while(x<[array count])
{
    if(![(myclass*)spr isInBounds]) {
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:x];
        x--;
    }
    x++;
}
```

**What is the fastest way to do this? Do you know other ways? 
Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your particular case, the best way is probably to save off the indexes of objects you don't care about in an `NSIndexSet` and use them after the loop to remove all the objects at once.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *is = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(myclass *spr, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([spr isInBounds]) {
        // do something
    } else {
        [is addIndex:idx];
    }
}];
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:is];
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the thing I was looking for!